# Trigonometric power series identity

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I've come across the identity:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{\pi(z-k)}{\sin(\pi z)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{\pi}{\pi\cos(\pi z)}=(-1)^{k}
\end{equation}
for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I'm unsure on how the first equality can be derived. How might I use the power series definitions of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [L'Hôpital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), $$\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{\pi (z-k)}{\sin(\pi z)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{\frac{d}{dz}\left (\pi (z-k)\right)}{\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sin(\pi z)\right)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{\pi}{\pi\cos(\pi z)}=(-1)^k$$